# Reaching $this value from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had these lines in my javascript file and it was working fine.

```
handleInput = function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
    id = $this.attr("id");
    alert(id);
}

....

something.bind("keyup", handleInput);
```

Then I decided to delay the input function and added following lines:

```
handleDelayedInput = function(e) {
    setTimeout(handleInput(e), 50);
}

.....

something.bind("keyup", handleDelayedInput);
```

But now `alert(id);` says undefined, because I think I couldn't pass the this to that function.

Am I right? How can I fix? Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: If you do `setTimeout(handleInput(e), 50);`, you execute the function instantly, not after 50 ms.

Comment: It's not the same to pass a function reference `handleInput` than the result of a function call `handleInput(e)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When jQuery calls the event handler it sets the context of the handler function. This isn't the case when handleInput is called in your second piece of code, so `this` is set to the default value `window`.

You can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set the context:

```
handleInput.call(this, e);
```

The difference between the two is that `apply` takes an array of arguments while you can pass the arguments to `call` one by one: `func.apply(context, arg1, arg2)`.

So your full code would be:

```
handleInput = function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
    id = $this.attr("id");
    alert(id);
}

handleDelayedInput = function(e) {
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        handleInput.call(element, e);
    }, 50);
}

something.bind("keyup", handleDelayedInput);
```

Note that, since we're using setTimout we need to find a way to pass the element to the timeout handler function. Also, in your code you're using the return value of `handleInput(e)` as the handler function - rather than `handleInput`.

I agree with Mike though, if you wrote handleInput yourself and you can modify it there's not point in using `this` instead of just passing the argument. If you still want to use handleInput as a direct handler somewhere else it would make sense to keep it the way you have it.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are no longer passing `handleInput` any object context like you were when calling it from your jQuery bind method. Personally I would rewrite the whole thing like this:

```
something.on("keyup", function(e) {
    var obj = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(obj) {
        alert(obj.attr("id");
    }, 50);
});
```

Note the use of `on()` instead of `bind()` which is now the preferred usage.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`apply` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var handleDelayedInput = function(e) {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        handleInput.apply(that, [e]);
    }, 50);
}

something.bind("keyup", handleDelayedInput); // Assuming something is a 
                                             // jQuery object
```

Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFDYc/).

Calling `handleInput` like this `setTimeout(handleInput(e), 50);` will lose the context, so `this` won't be what you expect within `handleInput` in that case.

Also, `setTimeout` should be passed a function, not the *result* of a function (unless the result is itself a function).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so:

```
handleInput = function(e) {
   var $this = $(this),
   id = $this.attr("id");
   setTimeout(function() {alert(id);}, 50);
}
```